# Why "Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [TTBA]" always come out?

Tags: ros, multimaster, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to learn and run multimaster in [ROCON](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert) with two turtlebots.
I launched amcl in two turtlebots, and try to flip amcl_pose to a server computer TTBA. But several lines with "Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [TTBA]" comes out in some terminals of turtelbots such as the termianl running amcl_demo.launch and the terminal flipping amcl_pose topic to sever TTBA.
I thought it was the wireless network problem. But I did ping from turtlebot two server TTBA. The results was normal.

So has anyone met this problem, or it is just a transient break of wireless link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155986/why-%22couldn%27t-find-an-af_inet-address-for-%5Bttba%5D%22-always-come-out?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2014-10-20**:
I also have the same problem. I have one machine running roscore linked via ethernet to a router. A laptop connects to that router via wifi, and has ROS_MASTER_URI defined. Both machines can ping each other. Laptop publish on /chatter, the other one sees it but can't echo and display that same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have found the solution on this post : http://answers.ros.org/question/163556/how-to-solve-couldnt-find-an-af_inet-address-for-problem/

---

Originally posted by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) with karma: 157 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1